# JavaScript Request Response Type

Tags: javascript, json, http-post

I am having an issue while following a tutorial on the subject of `HTTP` Requests. I can not get the code to auto-parse my response to `JSON`. This remains text. While it is stated that when specifying 'json: true' this sets the type to `json` and parses.

Tutorial: https://www.terlici.com/2015/04/28/couchdb-node-express.html

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/';
var db = 'js-express-librarytutorial/';
var id =  'document_id';

request.put(url + db);

request.put({
    url: url + db + id,
    body: {
        user: "Tom",
        message: "Document 2"
    },
    json: true
}, function(){request(url + db + id, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(typeof (body));
        console.log(body);
        console.log(body.user + ' : ' + body.message);
    })
});
```

Does anyone know how to trigger the auto-parsing of `http-calls`.

Comment: what does the console.log(body) shows?

Comment: Typeof(body) returns type : string.  The body itself is a string of the json send to the db. The idea being I get json back from the db since json is going out and it's bein saved in couch as json. There is no logic to it being a string on the return.

Comment: yeah it's a bit bizarr! and if you do console.log(JSON.parse(body)) does it shows a json then?

Comment: That does work. But it kinda beats the purpose. The json: true attribute should activate the auto-parsing.

Comment: Yes I know where the problem is! your body in the request is not JSON conform. you have to put your property-names in quotes like that: 
    body: {
        "user": "Tom",
        "message": "Document 2"
    },

Comment: Changing the quotes around the property-names does not fix the issue. I am using "request": "^2.82.0" at the moment.

Comment: hmm... it's a bit hard without a complete code! But plz just try this out body: JSON.stringify('{
        user: "Tom",
        message: "Document 2"
    }'),

Comment: If it doesn't work! just go to request.js in your node_modules and debug the function "Request.prototype.json" (just add debugger before the return self); and check what does the function with your "request"

Comment: Nope tried that as well.

This is the complete code. This connects to a local couchDB Instance. The only thing extra not posted here is the 'request' package. That's about it. Run this straight from the .js file.

I'll try the debugger as soon as possible. :)

Comment: good luck :-) and don't forget to post the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So research pointed out that my issue was due to scoping and nesting of callback functions in my original call.

The `json: true` argument on the request call sets the content-type to application/json. This automaticly leverages the parsing of any returning data:

```
request({url: url+db+"1", method: 'get', json: true}, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(typeof (body));
    console.log(body);
});
```

In this example no parsing is required and an Object is returned.

However when I nest the callback in an anonymous function with a seperate request call the content-type reverts back to text/*

With anonymous callback:

```
request.put(url + db, function(err, res, body){
    request.put({
        url: url + db + id,
        body: { user : "Tom", message: "Document"},
        json: true
    },function(){
        request(url+db+id,,  function(err, res, body){
            console.log(typeof (body));
            console.log(body);
        });
    });
});
```

This can be prevented by:

- Specifying the content type in seperate request call

Example:

```
request.get({...}, function(){request({url: url+db+id, method: "GET", json: true},  function(err, res, body){})}
```

- Remove the seperate request call and handle the return data in the callback directly:

Example:

```
request({url: url+db+"1", method: 'get', json: true}, function(err, res, body) {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the requestData in json like this :

```
    request.put({
    url: url + db + id,
    json: ' { "user": "Tom", "message": "Document 2" }'
}, function(){request(url + db + id, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(typeof (body));
        console.log(body);
        console.log(body.user + ' : ' + body.message);
    })
});
```

This may just work.
I don't have rights to comment on questions yet. Otherwise I should have suggested in comment. Hence, posting as an answer.
Please let me know if it works for you.